# Sum of squares of minors of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Having a orthogonal matrix $A$, prove that the sum of the squares of the minors formed from two lines (or columns) is 1. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Minors from two lines? What does that mean?

Comment: The 2x2 minors that can be formed with those two lines.

Comment: More generally, if you fix any $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k$ (positive integers smaller than the number of rows of $A$), then the sum of the squares of all minors formed from row $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k$ is $1$. To see this, you need to use three things: (1) [Jacobi's complementary minor theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87877), to replace the square of a minor by the product of this minor by the complementary minor of $A^{-1}$; (2) the observation that $A^{-1} = A^T$ (since $A$ is orthogonal), which turns this latter complementary minor ...

Comment: ... into a minor of $A$ using all rows other than $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k$; (3) Laplace expansion of $\det A$ in the rows $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k$. Alternatively, you might find it easier to work with exterior powers.